# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\lfloor s \rfloor$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, laplace-transform

How can we find the inverse Laplace transform of:

$[x]$ (*floor function*) ?
My question isn't LLaplace transform of floor function i asked the "inverse" laplace transform of floor function
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\text{floor}({s})\right)$$

Comment: What is $\lfloor 1+i\rfloor$?

Comment: Is the Laplace transform of any $f$ ever constant on an interval? Seems not at a first intuitive glance, for me.

Comment: If $F(s)$ the Laplace transform of $f(x)$ exists on some line $Re(s) = \sigma$, then it can be anything, since it is the Fourier transform of $e^{-\sigma x} f(x)$. but if it exists on some strip, then it has to be analytic on the interior of that strip. Of course $\lfloor x \rfloor$ isn't analytic (on the real line), while it isn't even defined for $x$ complex. hence, did you mean the Laplace transform ? or the Mellin transform ? or the (inverse) Fourier transform ?.. ( @jdods )

Comment: @user1952009, I don't know what op means, but I'm wondering about a real function $f$. Is there a real $f$ that has the Heaviside function or a square bump as its Laplace transform, e.g. like $(L(f))(s)=c$ on an interval and zero elsewhere? If so one could use that to construct the inverse Laplace transform of the floor function possibly.

Comment: @jdods ? I told you, the Laplace transform for a fixed $Re(s)$ is the Fourier transform : in a first time $f(x)$ has to be integrable, but then the Fourier transform is extended to so many things and nearly every function that you know which is increasing at most polynomially has a Fourier transform and hence can be in some sense the (bilateral) Laplace transform of some function on a vertical line of the complex plane.

Comment: @user1952009, It sounds like you are saying that I'm correct: that there does not exist $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $$\mathcal L[f](s)=\begin{cases} c \text{ for } s\in I\subseteq\mathbb R \\ 0 \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$
for some $c\in\mathbb R.$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}$, is the Fourier transform of $1_{|\xi| < 1/2}$, hence by the Fourier inversion theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions)... but it is its ***bilateral*** Laplace transform on $Re(s) = 0$ which is what you wrote.

Comment: @user1952009, I've never seen the bilateral Laplace transform. The issue was that I had forgotten that the inverse Laplace transform involved a complex contour integral and that the Laplace transform and the contour integral both imply existence of each other. Once I remembered that, your comments made sense.

Comment: @jdods : you should look at the Fourier transform

Answer (score 0):

$\because\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{c\}=c\delta(t)$

$\therefore\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\lfloor s\rfloor\}=\lfloor t\rfloor\delta(t)$